# Calculating a Factorial of a number in best time

Tags: algorithm, factorial

I am given N numbers i want to calculate sum of a  factorial modulus m
**For Example**

```
4 100
12 18 2 11

Ans = (12! + 18! +2!+11!)%100
```

Since the `1<N<10^5` and Numbers are from `1<Ni<10^17`
How to calculate it in efficient time.
Since the recursive approach will fail i.e

```
int fact(int n){
  if(n==1) return 1;
 return n*fact(n-1)%m;
}
```

Comment: Might be useful to observe that (N!)%m == 0 when m <= N.

Comment: '1<m<10^6' constraints in m

Comment: Actually, n! modulo 100 is 0 whenever n ≥ 10.

Comment: Another hint: It is not at all difficult to calculate 10000! modulo p where p is some prime number a bit larger than 10,000. The hint that it is not difficult should be enough to find out how it is done. No numbers of 30,000 digits are needed. Actually no numbers of eight or more digits are needed.

Comment: @gnasher729 would you explain with example

Comment: Looks similar to this question (from an ongoing contest): http://www.codechef.com/FEB15/problems/STFM

Answer (score 1):

if you precalculate factorials, using every operation %m, and will use hints from comments about factorials for numbers bigger than m you will get something like this

```
fact = new int[m];
f = fact[0] = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < m; i++)
{
    f = (f * i) % m;
    fact[i] = f;
}

sum = 0
for each (n in numbers)
{
    if (n < m)
    {
        sum = (sum + fact[n]) % m
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's best but it should work in a reasonable amount of time.

Upd: Code can be optimized using knowledge that if for some number j, (j!)%m ==0 than for every n > j (n!)%m ==0 , so in some cases (usually when m is not a prime number) it's not necessary to precalculate factorials for all numbers less than m

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var numbers = [12,18,2,11]

function fact(n) {
  if(n==1) return 1;
 return n * fact(n-1);
}

var accumulator = 0
$.each(numbers, function(index, value) {
    accumulator += fact(value)
})

var answer = accumulator%100

alert(accumulator)
alert(answer)
```

you can see it running here:

http://jsfiddle.net/orw4gztf/1/